# Excluded Purpose of License not clear. Confluent Community License

Tags: licensing

First time asking something on Law Stack Exchange and I am not sure if it is the right place. Usually use Stackoverflow but my question fits there even less.

I have Problems understanding the Confluent Community License. It is mostly Apache 2.0 but has an Excluded Purpose clause.

> “Excluded Purpose” is making available any software-as a-service,
> platform-as-a-service, infrastructure-as-a-service or other similar
> online service that competes with Confluent products or services that
> provide the Software.

From the few examples, they provide here it gets not clear to me (IT Student). If I am allowed to use it in my cases.
https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq/

They state:

> Can I download, modify, or redistribute the code? 
> Yes. The code is all still right there on GitHub.

> Can I embed Confluent Community software in software I distribute? 
> Yes, you can.

> Can I embed Confluent Community software in a SaaS offering I create? 
> Yes, provided the SaaS offering does not fall within the “Excluded Purpose” discussed above.

The simplest case that would solve all problems first.

Case 1:
I can go to a Customer install a simple Client with Confluent and charge a lot of money. The Customer will use it only for internal purpose. Does this count as a Competing use?  The first Statment says this is fine?
(The problem is not fixed. if the customer has the Licensing problem now)

Case 2:
Just like Case 1 but the environment I install Confluent has no possible access to Internet or the Hosted Services of Confluent. So it does not compete with “online” Services?

Case 3:
A Customer has a diverse set of my products and I want to provide a Centralized Interface to Data, generated only from my Products. I do not provide any Consuming use. I only provide Confluent to look into the data.

Case 4: (I know at least this would be ok)
I use Confluent within my Product family to produce and Consume Data. My Customer has no access to Confluent directly.

For me (a person with little understanding of law) this seems imprecise. Is this now good or bad for me?

Thanks for any Help in Advance I am also happy for recommendations where to put this question if this is the wrong place for it.

Comment: You need to distinguish between how the license applies to you as a consultant/installer and how the license applies to the customer you are installing it for.

Comment: This seems kind of like you're asking for legal advice.  It's also very broad and unclear about what specific legal question you're asking.  Ideally, your question would focus on a single, specific legal question (i.e., not "Is this now good or bad for me?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I don’t see any imprecision

Is what you are doing an “as-a-service” (i.e. a Cloud computing thing)?

If no, it’s not an “Excluded Purpose”.

If yes, does it:

1. Compete with a Confluent product, or
2. Compete with a service that provides Confluent software?

If no, it’s not an “Excluded Purpose”.

If yes, it is.